# Integrating webpagetest.org with CI Jenkins

Tags: performance, jenkins, phantomjs

We use webpagetest to monitor our websites and see how it is performing. I know we can integrate Yslow with Phantom js and then Jenkins.

Is there any way we can integrate webpagetest.org with CI jenkins.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might try [webpagetest-api](http://marcelduran.com/webpagetest-api/) which is a CLI tool and NodeJs module. You could fetch your test results and check for whatever metric you're after then output pass/no-pass.
Unfortunately CI integration does not come for free, you can either build your own integration with webpagetest-api node module or do some bash script magic with the CLI tool. Keep in mind webpagetest-api test (runTest) command is asynchronous, i.e.: it only schedule a test returning the test id so you can later check the results. There are some ways to integrate both test scheduling and fetching results, check it out [my post on last performance calendar](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/xmas-gift-webpagetest-api-swiss-army-knife/).